# Filling free space of two flex boxes with different widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have been creating a dropdown menu to select different languages. Heres the code:

```js
//Show DropDown Menu
var button = document.getElementById('select-lang-btn');
var ul = document.getElementById('language_dropdown');
button.onclick = function() {
  if (ul.style.display === 'block') {
    ul.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    ul.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
//Remove DropDown Menu if clicked outside
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  if (event.target != ul && event.target.parentNode != ul) {
    ul.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
//Select Language
function show(anything) {
  document.getElementById("selected-lang").innerHTML = anything
  document.getElementById('language_dropdown').style.display = 'none';
  if (anything === 'English') {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "gb.svg";
  } else if (anything === 'German') {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "de.svg";
  } else if (anything === 'Spanish') {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "es.svg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "global.svg";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #339699;
}

.language_section {
  width: 500px;
}

.reverse_language {
  width: 200px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
}

.language_section>div {
  display: flex;
}

#select-lang-btn {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
}

#selected-lang {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Open Sans";
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.language_flag {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.language_dropdown {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.language_dropdown>li>span:hover {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.language_dropdown>li>span {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.language_text {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Open Sans";
}

.language_text {
  line-height: 2;
}

.icon-angle-down {
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-right: 2px solid #444444;
  border-top: 2px solid #444444;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div class="language_section">
    <div><span id="select-lang-btn"><img id="select-lang-img" class="language_flag" src="img/flag/gb.svg"><a id="selected-lang">English</a><div class="icon-angle-down"></div></span></div>
    <ul class="language_dropdown" id="language_dropdown">
      <li onclick="show('English')"><span><img class="language_flag" src="img/flag/gb.svg"><a href="#" class="language_text">English</a></span></li>
      <li onclick="show('German')"><span><img class="language_flag" src="img/flag/de.svg"><a href="#" class="language_text">German</a></span></li>
      <li onclick="show('Spanish')"><span><img class="language_flag" src="img/flag/es.svg"><a href="#" class="language_text">Spanish</a></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="reverse_language"></div>

</div>
```

With this code I get the following result:

[image: First Version]

However there is free space, which I want to avoid. I have tried many different ways to get rid of this problem. The best I have come up to is to remove the witdth of `.language_section`. This is the result:

[image: Second Version]

But as you can see in my picture the dropdown menu changes too which I dont want too. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `position: relative` to `.language_section`

```
.language_section {
  position: relative;
}
```

And then add `position: absolute` to `.language_dropdown` for detaching the language list from `language_section` width

```
.language_dropdown {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute; /*Detach the current element to not depend on the parent width*/
  width: 250px; /*Width for your language list*/
}
```

The final result

[image]

Note that I set `250px` for language list, you can set it based on your needs

Full code

```js
//Show DropDown Menu
var button = document.getElementById('select-lang-btn');
var ul = document.getElementById('language_dropdown');
button.onclick = function() {
  if (ul.style.display === 'block') {
    ul.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    ul.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
//Remove DropDown Menu if clicked outside
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  if (event.target != ul && event.target.parentNode != ul) {
    ul.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
//Select Language
function show(anything) {
  document.getElementById("selected-lang").innerHTML = anything
  document.getElementById('language_dropdown').style.display = 'none';
  if (anything === 'English') {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "gb.svg";
  } else if (anything === 'German') {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "de.svg";
  } else if (anything === 'Spanish') {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "es.svg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("select-lang-img").src = "global.svg";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #339699;
}

.language_section {
  position: relative;
}

.reverse_language {
  width: 200px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
}

.language_section>div {
  display: flex;
}

#select-lang-btn {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
}

#selected-lang {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Open Sans";
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.language_flag {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.language_dropdown {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  /*Detach the current element to not depend on the parent width*/
  width: 250px;
  /*Width for your language list*/
}

.language_dropdown>li>span:hover {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.language_dropdown>li>span {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.language_text {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Open Sans";
}

.language_text {
  line-height: 2;
}

.icon-angle-down {
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-right: 2px solid #444444;
  border-top: 2px solid #444444;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div class="language_section">
    <div><span id="select-lang-btn"><img id="select-lang-img" class="language_flag" src="img/flag/gb.svg"><a id="selected-lang">English</a>
        <div class="icon-angle-down"></div>
      </span></div>
    <ul class="language_dropdown" id="language_dropdown">
      <li onclick="show('English')"><span><img class="language_flag" src="img/flag/gb.svg"><a href="#" class="language_text">English</a></span></li>
      <li onclick="show('German')"><span><img class="language_flag" src="img/flag/de.svg"><a href="#" class="language_text">German</a></span></li>
      <li onclick="show('Spanish')"><span><img class="language_flag" src="img/flag/es.svg"><a href="#" class="language_text">Spanish</a></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="reverse_language"></div>

</div>
```